# How to update a value in the db based on its previous value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, informix

How to update a value in the db based on its previous value considering more than one user may update the same value?

---

For example :

If My table like this :

```
id  lect_count

 1        15

 2        6
```

How to update the column `lect_count` to `lect_count+1` WHERE `id =` 1 for example ?

Comment: You done that in your question :) `lect_count = lect_count+1 WHERE id = 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as:

```
UPDATE tablename SET lect_count = lect_count + 1 WHERE id = 1
```